# How can I with javascript hide my sidenav when pressing back on my andriod?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, browser

I wonder if I can somehow close my sidenav in my html page when pressing the back button on android or in a browser.

```
function openSlideMenu(){
    document.getElementById('side-bar').style.width = "256px";
}
function closeSlideMenu(){
    document.getElementById('side-bar').style.width = "0px";
}
```

I've got this javascript so when I press a button it opens and closes my sidenav together with my stylesheet.

(I think it is good to mention that I'm pretty new with javascript.)

EDIT: I've googled a ton and found that with `window.onhashchange` together with `newURL` and `oldURL` you're able to manipulate a browsers history to make it work.

Maybe it's better to use `pushState` and `popState`.

Comment: When you are referring to pressing the back button, are you saying you want to collapse the navbar when changing pages on the website (while remaining on the website)? If you just make the default behavior for the side bar to have width 0 and only make the sidebar's width 256px when pressed, then this shouldn't be an issue (the sidebar will be minimized whenever a new page is loaded.

Comment: @JackMoody Yes I've seen some people use the `window.onhashchange` to control the back button. As you said I want to collapse the navbar with the back button, but only when it's open. Else it can go to previous history page, if there are any. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use back button to hide your sidenav

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(){
// overriding back button
document.getElementById('side-bar').style.width = "0px";
  });
```